# Sorting a list by a certain number?

Tags: java

I need to sort an array list which includes an age for each person, but I have to print out a list of people over 65. I know how to do this in SQL but not Java. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't sound like sorting - it sounds like filtering... I suggest you *try* it in Java (you'll probably want to use `if`) and then edit your question to include the code, unless you just succeed of course... in which case delete the question.

Comment: Yes filtering would be O(n)..whereas sorting and then filtering would be O(n logn)

Comment: Give it a good try, then show us your code :)

Comment: ```persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAge() > 65);```

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj: It's worth at least mentioning that that suggestion requires Java 8. (If the OP is new to Java, going to relatively advanced options with a not-quite-released version may not be a good idea.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Actually, I'd probably extend that to advanced options that are in released versions too; if we don't add explanation, that may end up just giving the OP a *second* thing that he's confused about.

Comment: @DennisMeng: True. I typically still don't take Java 7 as a given... although I wonder how long that will be the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Given how there's still a question involving Java *4* once in a while, we'll probably see Java 6 for a good while longer, even though it apparently hit EOL a good while ago.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Yes, but I think there's a reasonable *expectation* of Java 5/6 at the moment... you wouldn't think to mention that when writing an enhanced for loop, for example. If you're using an old version of Java you typically know that and would hopefully say so - it's a matter of when Java 6 becomes "old" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have the problem stated fully, then think about the algorithm you will use first (that is not language specific); then implement the algorithm.

If the problem is simply to list all people in an array whose age is over 65  (not 65 or older?), then you only need to loop through the array and, for each line, check to see if the age meets the criteria. If it does, print out the person.

If you need to sort the list, then do that first. (Use bubble sort or a more efficient sort if the list is long); then step through the list until you find the cutoff age and print out all the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you (a) want to sort a list of `Person` objects by their `age` value, *and then* (b) print out only those `Person`'s with an age greater than 65.

In java, one way to do the sort is to use a `Comparator`. The Javadoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can implement it as an inline class if you're only going to use it once, or as a separate class if you plan to use it in several places.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

Comparator<Person> example = new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }
};

Collections.sort(persons, example);
```

This implementation will sort by age. You can switch between ascending and descending order by switching `o1` and `o2`.

Another, possibly simpler way would be to implement `Comparable` in your Person class. 
To make your `Person` class comparable, modify its declaration thus:

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
```

And add the `compareTo()` method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {
    return this.getAge() - o.getAge();
}
```

However, this only lets you sort the class by one attribute. With `Comparator`'s, you can define more than one in order to sort by different attributes, such as first name, last name, and age.

To print out only `Person`'s whose age is greater than 65, just loop through the list's contents with an `if` condition checking each `Person`'s age and printing only if age > 65.